# UL LI Drop Down Menus pushes other html content downward

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

I thought my home-made custom UL LI CSS menus would work great, except for one minor detail. When the user clicks on the drop down, the drop down seems to move all the other HTML elements to the bottom.

Here is a before and after pic (separated by the black line):
[image]

Here is the HTML and CSS in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
.select {
    background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right top;
    border: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    width: 180px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.select:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: rgb(112,112,112);
}
.select ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul li {
    display: none;
    padding: 1px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.select ul li:hover {
    background: rgb(112,146,190);
    color: #FFF;
}
.selected {
    background: rgb(195,195,195);
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

    $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (!$clicked.hasClass("select")) {
            $(this).find('ul li').hide()
        }
    });

    $(".select").click(function () {
        $(this).find('ul li').toggle();
    });

    $(".select ul li").click(function(e) {

        if (e.ctrlKey) {

            e.stopPropagation()

            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) { $(this).removeClass('selected') }
            else {
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            }

            var c = $(this).parent().find("li.selected").length

            $(this).closest("div").contents().first().replaceWith((c > 1)?"(" +c+ ")":$(this).text())

        }
        else {
            $(this).closest("div").contents().first().replaceWith($(this).text());
            var id = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');

            $(this).closest('.select').find("ul li").removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }

    }); 
}




</script>

</head>

<body>
Numbers
<div class="select" id="reqtype">&nbsp;
    <ul>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li data-val="Column1">Column1</li>
        <li data-val="Column2">Column2</li>
        <li data-val="Column3">Column3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
Letters
<div class="select" id="letters">&nbsp;
    <ul>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>abcd</li>
        <li>efgh</li>
        <li>ijkl</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
Fruits
<div class="select" id="fruits">&nbsp;
    <ul>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>apples</li>
        <li>bananas</li>
        <li>oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle with a working scenario of your problem. Or edit this one: https://jsfiddle.net/650d04s3/

Comment: Position:absolute on the ul you want to show should work. Else please create a working fiddle

Comment: Position absolute is a hack.  The ULs are display:block.  You should be using SELECT elements instead of ULs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick way to get it set up. Put a `position: relative` on your `.select` like this

```
.select {
    background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right top;
    border: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    width: 180px;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then update your first drop down menu like this:

```
#reqtype ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    width: 188px;
    left: -1px; /*this is to address the 1px border*/
    background: red;
    z-index: 10
}
```

Truthfully the present code seems like a lot just to have a basic drop down menu. I am sure there are easier methods to use to achieve what you are trying to accomplish.

[Heres a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vg2zdw41/1/). Hope that helps

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much for your dedication and your time :)